# Regex w/ JavaScript on some multiple choice questions

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to parse a .docx of multiple choice questions for Anki flashcards.

I want to assemble from the docx a match group of 'Questions' and 'Answers'.

While trying to do the questions, I can't get the regex to match each of them in the way that I want.

Example questions:

```
    1.  Hormones and other signal molecules bind with ____ affinities to their receptors and are produced at concentrations ____ their KD values.
a.
low; far above
b.
moderate; far above
c.
moderate; equivalent to
d.
high; far below
e.
very high; equivalent to


ANS:    E    

    2.  Steroid hormones, such as glucocorticoids, effect their action by:
a.
binding to a plasma membrane receptor, which stimulates a signal transduction pathway within the cell
b.
binding to a plasma membrane receptor, which stimulates the receptor to enter the cell
c.
entering into the cell and affecting the production of secondary messengers
d.
entering into the cell and then acting as transcription regulators
e.
both a and d are correct


ANS:    E    

    3.  All are unifying features of polypeptide hormones EXCEPT that they are:
a.
originally synthesized with signal sequences.
b.
synthesized as inactive preprohormones.
c.
activated from preprohormones to hormones by phosphorylation.
d.
may produce several different peptide hormones with suitable processing.
e.
all are true.


ANS:    C    

    4.  Each of the following statements is true EXCEPT:
a.
epinephrine is an amino acid derivative
b.
steroid hormones can enter cells and regulate transcription
c.
insulin is a polypeptide hormone
d.
progesterone is a polypeptide hormone
e.
all of the above are true


ANS:    D    

    5.  The acrosome reaction, involving ion channel induced release of acrosomal enzymes used by sperm to attack the egg, is induced by:
a.
estrogen.
b.
testosterone.
c.
dihydrotestosterone (DHT).
d.
progesterone.
e.
cortisol.


ANS:    D
```

I'm using `/(\d.)[^\d][^ANS$]+/gm` but it keeps skipping the 2nd and 3rd questions, and more when parsing a whole document.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: `[^\d]` better written as `\D`.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to get, at least what would be the desired output given your sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also try an easier solution:

```
(\d\.)[\s\S]*?(?=ANS)
```

It will not break by anything except `ANS`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/Qnwl8b/2/

Comment: this actually worked the best, once modified to accommodate larger numbers of questions with: /(\d{1,2}\.)[\s\S]*?(?=ANS)/gm

Comment: @mjabraham It is not the best, just measure its performance against mine. And it does not match answers.

Comment: @Ibrahim When parsing long text (or text of arbitrary length), you should not use lazy dot matching with a lookahead. What `[\s\S]*?(?=ANS)` does is it skips `[\s\S]*?` pattern first and checks for `ANS`, and when `ANS` is not found, the `[\s\S]*?` pattern is "expanded" (it is the action contrary to backtracking). It does these operations at every single location inside the string. These patterns should be unrolled for better performance.

Answer (score 1):

The `(\d.)[^\d][^ANS$]+` pattern matches a digit (`\d`) followed with any char (`.`), then followed with any char other than digit (`[^\d]`), then followed with any 1 or more chars other than `A`, `N`, `S` and `$` (`[^...]` is a negated character class where `$` loses its special meaning and it matches a single char from the class, not a sequence).

To fix the regex, you may use

```
/^\s*(\d+\..*(?:\r?\n(?!\s*ANS:).*)*)\r?\n\s*(ANS:.*)/gm
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4CzB4k/2)

**Details**

- `^`- start of a line (since `m` modifier makes `^` match the start of a line rather than the whole string)
- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespaces
- `(` - Group 1 start:

  - `\d+` - 1 or more digits
  - `\.` - a dot
  - `.*` - the rest of the line
  - `(?:\r?\n(?!\s*ANS:).*)*` - 0 or more consecutive occurrences of

    - `\r?\n` - a CRLF or LF line break...
    - `(?!\s*ANS:)` - not followed with 0+ whitespaces (`\s*`) followed with 
      `ANS:` substring (the `(?!...)` is a negative lookahead that fails the match if 
      its pattern is found immediately to the right of the current location)
    - `.*` - the rest of the line
- `)` - Group 1 end
- `\r?\n` - a line break
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(ANS:.*)` - Group 2 capturing `ANS:` and the rest of the line.

JS demo:

```js
var rx = /^\s*(\d+\..*(?:\r?\n(?!\s*ANS:).*)*)\r?\n\s*(ANS:.*)/gm;
var s = "1.  Hormones and other signal molecules bind with ____ affinities to their receptors and are produced at concentrations ____ their KD values.\r\na.\r\nlow; far above\r\nb.\r\nmoderate; far above\r\nc.\r\nmoderate; equivalent to\r\nd.\r\nhigh; far below\r\ne.\r\nvery high; equivalent to\r\n\r\n\r\nANS:    E    \r\n\r\n    2.  Steroid hormones, such as glucocorticoids, effect their action by:\r\na.\r\nbinding to a plasma membrane receptor, which stimulates a signal transduction pathway within the cell\r\nb.\r\nbinding to a plasma membrane receptor, which stimulates the receptor to enter the cell\r\nc.\r\nentering into the cell and affecting the production of secondary messengers\r\nd.\r\nentering into the cell and then acting as transcription regulators\r\ne.\r\nboth a and d are correct\r\n\r\n\r\nANS:    E    \r\n\r\n    3.  All are unifying features of polypeptide hormones EXCEPT that they are:\r\na.\r\noriginally synthesized with signal sequences.\r\nb.\r\nsynthesized as inactive preprohormones.\r\nc.\r\nactivated from preprohormones to hormones by phosphorylation.\r\nd.\r\nmay produce several different peptide hormones with suitable processing.\r\ne.\r\nall are true.\r\n\r\n\r\nANS:    C    \r\n\r\n    4.  Each of the following statements is true EXCEPT:\r\na.\r\nepinephrine is an amino acid derivative\r\nb.\r\nsteroid hormones can enter cells and regulate transcription\r\nc.\r\ninsulin is a polypeptide hormone\r\nd.\r\nprogesterone is a polypeptide hormone\r\ne.\r\nall of the above are true\r\n\r\n\r\nANS:    D    \r\n\r\n    5.  The acrosome reaction, involving ion channel induced release of acrosomal enzymes used by sperm to attack the egg, is induced by:\r\na.\r\nestrogen.\r\nb.\r\ntestosterone.\r\nc.\r\ndihydrotestosterone (DHT).\r\nd.\r\nprogesterone.\r\ne.\r\ncortisol.\r\n\r\n\r\nANS:    D  "
var m;
var qst=[], ans=[];
while (m = rx.exec(s)) {
  qst.push(m[1].trim());
  ans.push(m[2].trim());
}
document.body.innerHTML += "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(qst, 0, 4) + "</pre>";
document.body.innerHTML += "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(ans, 0, 4) + "</pre>";
```

Comment: Follow up question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46878545/using-regex-with-javascript-on-answers-to-multiple-choice-questions

Comment: The version that captures both the question and answer is [`^\s*(\d+\..*(?:\r?\n(?!\s*ANS:).*)*)\r?\n\s*(ANS:.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/4CzB4k/2), see [**the JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/cn26ctrn/).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select only the questions, you can simply use:

```
/\d.+/gm
```

If you want to select each question and its answers, you can use:

```
/\d\D+(?=ANS)/gm
```

This is assuming that the questions and answers don't include numbers in them.